# how to get data of json format

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to get the data in json format. But I am unable to get that data. Data is in this format

```
{"make":"VOLKSWAGEN","dateOfFirstRegistration":"23 July 2009","yearOfManufacture":"2009","cylinderCapacity":"1968cc","co2Emissions":"167 g/km","fuelType":"DIESEL","taxStatus":"Tax not due","colour":"SILVER","typeApproval":"M1","wheelPlan":"2 AXLE RIGID BODY","revenueWeight":"Not available","taxDetails":"Tax due: 01 October 2016","motDetails":"Expires: 28 April 2017","taxed":true,"mot":true,"vin":"WVGZZZ5NZAW007903","model":"Tiguan","transmission":"Manual","numberOfDoors":"5","sixMonthRate":"","twelveMonthRate":""}
```

I have tried this.

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data=json_decode($response,TRUE);
echo $data->make;
```

Comment: echo `$data["make"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
echo $data['make'];
```

Because json_decode converted the data into associative arrays, not into the std object array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $json = '{"make":"VOLKSWAGEN","dateOfFirstRegistration":"23 July 2009","yearOfManufacture":"2009","cylinderCapacity":"1968cc","co2Emissions":"167 g/km","fuelType":"DIESEL","taxStatus":"Tax not due","colour":"SILVER","typeApproval":"M1","wheelPlan":"2 AXLE RIGID BODY","revenueWeight":"Not available","taxDetails":"Tax due: 01 October 2016","motDetails":"Expires: 28 April 2017","taxed":true,"mot":true,"vin":"WVGZZZ5NZAW007903","model":"Tiguan","transmission":"Manual","numberOfDoors":"5","sixMonthRate":"","twelveMonthRate":""}
';

   var_dump(json_decode($json));
   var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch value from json_decode using an array key not an object.

Try :

```
echo $data["make"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Return json string as object

```
$json_obj = json_decode($response);
    print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($json_obj->make);
```

**OR**

Return json string as array

```
$data=json_decode($response,TRUE);  
    print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($data['make']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data=json_decode($response,TRUE);
echo $data['make'];
```